# How to avoid following "If" conditions if the first "If" is true

Tags: vb.net

I want to make my first `If` to stop at `"Incorrect user and password"`, but it goes to the second and third `If` saying `"incorrect user"` and `"incorrect password"` after `"incorrect user and password"`.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim numAttempts As Double = 0

    Private Sub btnok_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click
        Dim User As String = "ShaoHecc"
        Dim Password As String = "daedric123"
        Dim loginuser As String
        Dim loginpassword As String
        Dim wrong As String = False

        loginpassword = Val(txtpass.Text)
        loginuser = Val(txtuser.Text)
        txtpass.Text = loginpassword
        txtuser.Text = loginuser

        If txtuser.Text = User And
            txtpass.Text = Password Then
            MessageBox.Show("Access Granted!")
        ElseIf txtuser.Text = loginuser And
            txtpass.Text = loginpassword Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password incorrect, " & numAttempts & " / 3 attempts left")
        End If

        If txtuser.Text = User = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username incorrect, you have " & numAttempts & " / 3 attempts left.")
            txtuser.Text = Nothing
        End If

        If txtpass.Text = Password = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password incorrect, you have " & numAttempts & " / 3 attempts left.")
            txtpass.Text = Nothing
        End If

        If numAttempts = 3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Maxiumum number attempts reached, you have been denied access.")
            Application.Exit()
        Else
            numAttempts = numAttempts + 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You put the later `If` blocks inside the first one.  Code inside an `If` block only gets executed if the condition tested is `True` so if you only want another `If` statement evaluated if that condition is `True` then put it inside the `If` block.

Comment: Your second `If` statement doesn't really make sense though.  Firstly, the condition `txtuser.Text = User = False` is badly written.  That should be `txtuser.Text <> User`.  Secondly, that should be an `Else` statement associated with the first `If` statement.  Perhaps you should pick up a pen and paper and trying writing out your logic first, before trying to implement it in code.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really new to this. I don't quite understand how to fix my code according to your first comment, could you tell me more on how I should proceed with this?

Comment: You don't know how to put one thing inside another?

Comment: Oh sorry thought you were saying that I put if blocks in the first one and it was wrong, nevermind

Comment: As what @jmcilhinney said, it is a good practice to jot down how you'd like to implement it in code. Since you're new to this, you'd easily get confused by the "coding logic". I can see that your code separately verifies your predefined `User` and `Password` which is kind of unnecessary. You can still do it this way, perhaps along with your own specific reason. However, I'd suggest that combines the verification for both together at once would be much more easier. Then prompts your message box in a way like `"Invalid User or Password"`. Just like how real-life login systems work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have far too much code there than what is needed.
2. You are also using legacy VB6 code where it is not needed.
3. You appear to have no idea of variables and variable types.

Let me explain a little... Let's work backwards...

Variable types, of which there are many, each are required and/or recommended for a particular task. In your example you have a `numAttempts` which is used to count the failed attempts, however, you have it as a `Double` >>> `Dim numAttempts As Double`, it's wrong and wasteful, just use a standard `Integer` for a whole number in this situation. This is also of interest: `Dim wrong As String = False`. There are two things fundamentally wrong here. A string is `Text`, which means it should always have quotes surrounding the text >>> `Dim wrong As String = "False"`. However, using something to test for `True` or `False` should be a `Boolean` so actually, the correct usage and syntax should be `Dim wrong As Boolean = False`.

Legacy VB6 code. Never a good thing to mix and match pre-.NET code with .NET code. You're using `Val`, don't do it. Also, it's worth noting that your usage is not needed and simply incorrect. You are using: `loginpassword = Val(txtpass.Text)`. Why are you doing this? What do you think is happening here? It's going to try to convert whatever is in your `txtpass.Text` (string) to a `Double` (not a string) then put it into `loginpassword` (string).

I hope you don't take offence, I'm just trying to get you to see some flaws so you can try to improve and get to love programming like many people here already do so.

SO let's get back to your original code and question. Below is a simplified version of what you want to do.

Try it, understand it, and then change it as you see fit. For example, if you want a separate Username/Password check.

Good Luck!

```
Dim numAttempts As Integer = 3
Dim User As String = "ShaoHecc"
Dim Password As String = "daedric123"

Private Sub btnok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click

    'Check if Username or Password are incorrect
    If Not txtuser.Text = User Or Not txtpass.Text = Password Then
        numAttempts -= 1
        If numAttempts = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Maxiumum number attempts reached, you have been denied access.")
            Application.Exit()
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password, you have " & numAttempts & " attempts left.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Username and Password are correct
    MessageBox.Show("Access Granted!")
    numAttempts = 3 'Reset if needed
End Sub
```